# MySQL Replication Error, can't stop slave

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5

When I run command `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`, I see

- `Slave_IO_Running : 'Yes'`
- `Slave_SQL_Running : 'No'`

What I've usually done to fix this is to run

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GLOBAL sql_slave_skip_counter = 1;
START SLAVE;
```

It did not work this time.

When I ran `STOP SLAVE;`, I get `SQL Error (1192): Can't execute the given command because you have active locked tables or an active transaction."`

I've never seen this before. What can I do to get past it?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of MySQL you have installed in your slave server?

This behaviour seems to be a bug fixed starting from MySQL 5.5.0

see [MySQL 5.5.0 Changelog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/news-5-5-0.html)

in:

> **Important Change**: **Replication**: MyISAM transactions replicated to a
>   transactional slave left the slave in an unstable condition. This was
>   due to the fact that, when replicating from a nontransactional storage
>   engine to a transactional engine with autocommit disabled, no BEGIN
>   and COMMIT statements were written to the binary log; thus, on the
>   slave, a never-ending transaction was started.
>
> The fix for this issue includes enforcing autocommit mode on the slave
>   by replicating all autocommit=1 statements from the master. (Bug
>   29288)

Bug details here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=29288

If it is, "simply" before upgrade your slave server, then you can plan an upgrade of the master.

Comment: I am surprised nobody upvoted this one yet. I remember seeing this and decided to wait, then forgot about it. Since it came back with no upvotes, I give you +1 because your answer is very plausible and would possibly show up if a patch was missed for anyone using any version of MySQL 5.5 before MySQL 5.5.8.